# format column headers during concat,oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I need to format column headers in the output of sql while using concat
Eg:

```
SELECT '' || to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') as DATE || ',' || ENO|| ',' || NAME|| ''  
FROM EMP;
```

would retrieve me

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

Need the output as:

```
DATE   ENO   NAME
-----------------
251013 7560  RAM
251013 7561  ROSS
```

This format works

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME as "DATE,ENO,NAME" 
FROM EMP
```

but I have an issue with

> ORA-00972: identifier is too long

when the length of column names inside as "" exceeds 30 characters

Eg:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME ||
       ',' || EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER as "DATE,ENO,NAME,EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER" 
FROM EMP;
```

Comment: Maximal length of identifier in Oracle is 30 characters, so alias of your column cannot exceed 30 characters, and that's why you're getting this error.

Comment: It's not a single column name that is exceeding 30 characters

Comment: So, trying to find out if there is a way to avoid ORA-00972 while having multiple column names in alias using concat

Comment: You HAVE a single name exceeding 30 characters, the alias. **Alias is an identifier**, just like a column name. Here you have just a string which contains names of column from your table, and this "string" is an identifier, an alias for your concatenated columns. It's not possible to specify a longer alias.

Comment: Is there a workaround (to rewrite this query) to achieve the desired output format?

Comment: It is not possible to specify a longer alias. You could, however, make a `UNION` with a single row from `DUAL` with your header, order by some additionally added column and you'll have what you need (more or less). I guess you are saving the result to a file? In this approach, the header would actually be a row, but its value would be the string you want for the header.

Comment: I suggest to use an abstract columnname like "Combined", or try Przemyslaws approach. Unless you dont specify more what you are trying, there will no better solution

Comment: Thou canst try something like `COLUMN DENE_ID HEADING 'Date, ENo, Name|Employee_Identification_Number'` and then try something akin to your query: `SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME ||','||Chr(10)|| EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER as "DENE_ID" 
FROM EMP;`

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this output you have to build your query like this
`SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME as "DATE,ENO,NAME" FROM EMP`

Comment: This format works

SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME as "DATE,ENO,NAME" FROM EMP

but I have an issue with ORA-00972: identifier is too long when the length of column names inside as "" exceeds 30 characters

Eg:

SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME || ',' || EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER as "DATE,ENO,NAME,EMPLOYEE_IDENTIFICATION_NUMBER" FROM EMP;

Throws ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the alias, if you really need it, at the end of the `SELECT` clause. Also the empty strings (`''`) can be removed:

```
SELECT to_char(sysdate,'ddmmyyyy') || ',' || ENO || ',' || NAME as DATE FROM EMP;
```